# Lower motion blur for some objects?

Tags: animation, motion-blur

I want to know, how to lower motion blur for some objects in an animation. Camera is moving so fast, its making an object too blurry to tell what it is.

Comment: You want different motion blur on different objects? Or you just want less overall so that it's not so blurry anymore?

Comment: Motion Blur calculated due rendering is for entire scene. To affect motion blur per specific object you would have to use Compositors Motion Blur.

Comment: I want lower motion blur for specific objects. But keep it the same for the rest of the scene.

Comment: @vklidu Is it possible to use the compositor to add different motion blur shutter curves? (like Scene > Motion Blur > Shutter Curve). Not sure how to combine various blurred images together.

Comment: @MrG ... does Answer solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to add different motion blur per object here is a sketch in Compositor.

You would have to isolate (matte) the object and apply blur just on that. Here I used Cryptomatte.
All depends how complex or where the object is placed in space, if there is something infront covering the object or so ...

(Cubes are moving the same speed ... **Cube A** *Blur* 4, **Cube B** *Blur* 2)

[image]
[image]

Proper way to combine it back is to use *Z-combine* node, but it gives me some crop on blur so I'm missing something here :)

---

I wasn't sure about the *Shutter Curve*, but it seems like there can be achieved something ...

[image]

I'm not an experienced in Motion Blur, so I can be wrong :)